# What does "slightly wooly" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4904533/5812238):

> Depending on where you look, you'll get slightly different answers. I've read about the subject a lot, and here's my distillation; again, these are **slightly wooly** and others may disagree.

Could you say, please, what does "slightly wooly" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Wooly is the US English spelling of [**woolly**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/woolly#English), which literally means (according to Wiktionary)

> Made of wool.

However, in this case, the meaning is not literal but figurative:

> Of thinking, principles, etc, based on emotion rather than logic.
>
> Unclear, fuzzy, hazy, cloudy.

In this case, I think the last meaning is intended.

[**Slightly**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slightly) means

> To a small extent or degree.

So the author wants to say that what he read is to some extent unspecific.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "wooly" is a BrE slang expression meaning, *unclear or fuzzy* or, in this case, *lacking sharp definition at the edges*.  The writer is trying to say that the following are *rough* definitions for testing, and there may be some overlap between one type of testing and another.  He's basically asking people not to pick at any discrepancies.

In AmE we're more likely to say "fuzzy" than "woolly", to mean the same thing:

> Although the theory is sound, its author is **fuzzy** on the details of how it can be applied to the real world.